# Limit of $[\frac{1}{x}]$ as $x{\rightarrow0}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am trying to prove that the $$lim_{x\rightarrow0}[\frac{1}{x}]$$ does not exist with $\epsilon-\delta$ definition. I am struggling with how to structure the proof. I graphed the function and when we approach the function from $x\le0$ and $x\ge0$ we get $-\inf$ and $\inf$ respectively implying the function is not continuous at $x=0$.

In order to prove limit does not exist we can use contradiction. Say the limit exists and it is $L$. From the epsilon delta definition, say we fix epsilon to be 1. Then there is a delta such that $\forall |x| < \delta$, $|[\frac{1}{x}] - L| < 1$. If we look at only x > 0. We can choose a $x = 1/n < \delta for,  n\in \mathbb Z^+ $. $$[\frac{1}{x}] = n$$. We can always pick a 1/n such that the epsilon inequality does not hold as the $[\frac{1}{x}]$ is unbounded near 0 but I can't complete the formal argument from here.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost done. Just pick $n >L+1, n>\frac 1 {\delta}$ and take $x=\frac 1 n$. Then you get $|x|<\delta$ but you don't have $|[\frac{1}{x}] - L| < 1$.

Answer (score 0):

You have proved the statement almost 100%. Notice, you have assumed that if some $L$ exists as a limit for the function $[1/x]$, then $∀ \varepsilon > 0$ there exists $δ > 0$ such that $∀|x|<δ, |[1/x]−L|<\varepsilon$. But for epsilon equal to 1, there also exists $δ$ such that $∀|x|<δ, |[1/x]−L|<1$. But, if you choose $N$ sufficiently large such that $x=1/N$ is less than $\delta$ (this can be done by Archimedean Property) and $N-L>1$ (since $L$ is finite, you can always do that), then you have contradicted that $L$ is a limit. Thus, any finite $L$ cannot be a limit for the function.